# Is it better to use a Class or Variables in the Signature of a Method?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've often wondered. In terms of "best practice" when writing a Function, be it Local or in a Module / Class, it is better to use:

```
Public Function WhichIsBetter(ByVal tmpUser As String, _
                              tmpPassword As String) As Boolean
    'Do something
End Function
```

Or

```
Public Class User
    Public Property tmpUser As String
    Public Property tmpPassword As String
End Class

Public Function WhichIsBetter(ByVal tmpUser As User) As Boolean
     'Do something
End Function
```

Comment: it's a matter of style. Do whichever is clearer.

Comment: I've always used both, dependent on how often I'll be using the Function and/or how detailed the Function is, but is there any "official recommendation?"

Comment: The 2nd snippet just isn't valid code, a function must be written inside a Module or a Class.  There's a huge difference between the two, the 2nd one would have to use the Shared keyword to be equivalent.  Don't use Modules, they are only there for compatibility with old VB code.  There's nothing pretty about having the declarations inside of a module getting added to the global namespace.

Comment: It depends on context.  If you are passing in more than three arguments, then you should start to look at the latter version.  However if you are expecting other users to use this function as part of a public API then the first one would probably make more sense in this instance.

Comment: @HansPassant So if I need Public / Global variables in an app, where should I be declaring them?

Answer (score 1):

If no prior analysis has been done on code architecture, I would always start with `ByVal tmpUser As String, tmpPassword As String` signature and see how code evolves.

If you find yourself passing `tmpUser` and `tmpPassword` around very often, i.e. every function has a signature of these parameters + something else, chances are you need to be passing a User object instead. Consider using an object even more, if you happen to be adding the same parameter to multiple functions often.